# is there any better way to use Youtube PHP API

Tags: php, ajax, curl, youtube, youtube-api

I am using youtube php Zend API Library.

In this API first I send request to get the temporary/confirmation code.

Then an request to get the access token.

After this I want to fetch the user information then another request makes to

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default
```

for current user It returns the url with userId

Then finally I get the user Information from that url which is in xml form.

I am fed up by these so many requests it takes much time as well.

Is there another way to get these thing by reducing the number of `curl/ajax` requests.

Comment: Is the problem that you need to query multiple users and it takes too much time?

Comment: yes I have mentioned it in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `curl_multi_*` to do requests for different users in parallel. It won't speed up the process for every single user, but since you can do 10-30 or more requests in parallel, it will speed up the whole deal.

The only complication is that you will need separate cookie file for every request. Here's sample code to get your started:

```
$chs = array();
$cmh = curl_multi_init();
for ($t = 0; $t < $tc; $t++)
{
    $chs[$t] = curl_init();
    // set $chs[$t] options
    curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
}

$running=null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($cmh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

for ($t = 0; $t < $tc; $t++)
{
    $contents[$t] = curl_multi_getcontent($chs[$t]);
    // work with $contencts[$t]
    curl_multi_remove_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
    curl_close($chs[$t]);
}
curl_multi_close($cmh);
```